# iPhone 4 cannot restore to iOS 5 in DFU mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I download the iOS 5 firmware file for my iPhone 4 (GSM): iPhone3,1_5.0_9A334_Restore.ipsw. I put my iPhone in DFU mode and Alt+Clicked the Restore button in iTunes. I then selected the .ipsw that I downloaded and then it extracts the software and gives me the following message:

[image: iPhone Firmware error screenshot]

I just can't seem to upgrade the phone, any ideas anyone?

Comment: Is there any reason you pulled the file yourself? You should delete it, and let iTunes get it for you (it will check online when it detects your device in DFU mode). As the error says, the IPFW is corrupt.

Comment: I agree with cksum, this is a case where going through the process as recommended by Apple is the best way to go and it should take care of this problem: Connect iPhone to computer, download upgrade, upgrade iPhone. The only thing I would add is to force a backup of your current iPhone in iTunes before you do this just to make doubly sure you're backed up before upgrading.

Comment: Thanks all! I have tried it, but the iTunes connection cuts out for just about any reason and then needs to restart the download. That's why I choose to download the .ipsw myself.

Answer (score 2):

As iOS 5 is public, there is no need to download the firmware file yourself. Just click on 'search for updates' and let it upgrade.

Comment: Yes, but you don't understand, I have a line that's not very consistent and the slightest dip in signal makes iTunes stop the download and then restart it. That's why I use Speed Download to download it cause it's reliable and the download can continue if it should quit for some reason. The fact that ipsw files get corrupted so quickly is just tiring.

Comment: Download it from the official Apple website: http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-8358.20111012.FFc34/iPhone3,1_5.0_9A334_Restore.ipsw